# Is it possible to assign different categories to the same product, by Store View?

Tags: store-view, category-products, scope, magento-1.14

everyone.

I have a little problem, and I hope you can help me. Suppose I have a Site that has two Websites: **Website1** and **Website2**. Respectively each has its **StoreView1** and **StoreView2**:

```
--Website1
----StoreView1
--Website2
----StoreView2
```

And I haven the next Category structure:

```
--Default Category
----Shoes
----Outlet
------Shoes
```

So, if a Product is Shoes, It should be assigned to Category **Shoes**. In additional, if the product is **Outlet**, It should be assigned to **Outlet > Shoes**. But, a product can be Outlet in **StoreView1** but not in **StoreView2**. So, I need that the product in **StoreView1** to be assigned to **Shoes** and **Outlet > Shoes**, but in **StoreView2** to be assigned only to **Shoes**.

But, when I try it:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(<id of StoreView1>)->load(<Product Id>);
$product->setCategoryIds(array(<Shoes id>, <Outlet > Shoes Id>)->save();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(<id of StoreView2>)->load(<Product Id>);
$product->setCategoryIds(array(<Shoes id>)->save();
```

The product always take the last categories I assigned. In other words, it assigns the categories to all stores equally, instead of assigning per store. I tried in Admin, changing product categories, positioned on the scope of the store view, but also the change is reflected in the other store view too. Are product categories always global? Is there no way to assign them for Store View?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product - category relation s global. It does not depend on the store view or website.  What you can do is to have a different category tree on the second website. But this will result in duplicate categories.

Comment: You are right, I saw catalog_category_product table, and it only have category_id and product_id, not store_id... I think I will need to create two outlet categories, one for each store :/ Thanks!